# Measurements are slowing down for the ultrasonic sensors HC-SR04 and RCWL-1601

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, sensors

I have the problem with two different ultrasonic sensors (HC-SR04 and RCWL-1601).
The measurements starts pretty good and after about 10...20 measurements they start to slow down and I receive the new measurements once in about 10...12 seconds. I tried to change interval between measurements from 0.1 sec. to 1 sec. (now it is 0.25 sec.) and still receive the same results. Here is the code I use. The same code I saw on many sites and as they claim it works well. What could be wrong?

```
 def distance():
    GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
    time.sleep(0.05)

    #Set Trigger to High
    GPIO.output(TRIG, True)
    time.sleep(0.00001) #Set Trigger to Low after 0.01ms
    GPIO.output(TRIG, False)

    #Saving the start time
    StartTime = 0
    StopTime = 0

    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 0:
        StartTime = time.time()

    #Saving the end time

    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 1:
        StopTime = time.time()

    #Calculating of the time difference
    TimeElapsed = StopTime - StartTime

    #Multiplying by the sonic speed (343000 mm/s)
    #and dividing by 2 because of the double distance there and back

    distance = (TimeElapsed*343000)/2
    return distance
try:
    while True:
        dist = distance()
        print ("Measured distance = %.1f mm" %dist)
        time.sleep(0.25)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("Measurements interrupted by the User.")
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: maybe it is purely hardware issue? using your sensors could warm them up and for burn-protection they slow down?

Comment: Don't think so. two different types of sensors and several samples of each type. That is the normal working load for them.